# Is it possible to use viewport zoom to scale html for desktop browser?

Tags: html, css

We save and display files that are e-mailed to our webservices. Sometimes we want to let users preview the files. For images and pdf:s we can easily scale them down to an appropriate size(for pdf:s we use iframes).

However sometimes the e-mailed content contain html. Is there some way to scale it down to fit  within the size of an iframe? Like widt=device-width scale=1 for mobile? We can accept a fixed width if necessary, however, we don't know the width of the content.

Comment: Have you tried CSS scaling?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the `<html>` and `<body>` font size with CSS and then you could style your HTML that should scale with the `rem` unit.

```
html,
body {
  font-size: 100%;  // flexible baseline
}

html {
  font-size: 1em; // Set in ems, assuming a browser default of 16px
}

.module h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Css-property `zoom` can do what you need.